# sql2005 maintance plan 4 bak files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

my goal is simple. i want to have SQL keep a nightly backup of a DB for a rolling 5 days.

so each night at some time i want a new DB backup made and one deleted such that i have a rolling 5 days on disk.

i am trying to get a maintenance plan set up to handle this work and have the saving of the file done (i think). i have the backups being appended so a single bak file will contain the rolling 5 days (not sure this will work 0 cause how will SQL know what to delete, and deleting the single bak file will remove all the backups).

as you can tell i am having problems figuring out how to remove older backups fo the DB so that i have only the most recent 5 on disk.

any tips for me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to backup to individual files instead of combining backups. The clean up task isn't smart enough to look inside a single file and remove old backups.

Then drop in a Maintainence Cleanup sub task to remove files older than 5 days.

Comment: how can i make it so each nightly backup has a date appended to its name? i think i saw this done in the past but cant remember how

Comment: Once you begin backing up to individual files, each file should automatically have the date and time in the filename.

Comment: i am selecting backup to disk option and adding a folder and file name. then i have an overwrite or append option. either way i dont see how this gets me separate bak files daily

Comment: thanks, i see my problem now. bad selection of options ...

Answer (score 1):

Add a Maintenance Cleanup Task to your maintenance plan. With this task you can choose to delete backup files older than a certain date. I have not tried to do this with a single backup file so I'm not 100% sure if this will work for you.

Is there a reason you want to do it with a single file?

Comment: i dont care if i have many files, i would actually prefer to have a file for each day... but cant seem to get it to work like this. if this was done the clean up would be simple to delete any files of type .BAK older than 5 days.

Comment: That seems strange. By default the maintenance plan wizard creates individual files for the databases every day. All you should need is a Back Up Database Task and a Maintenance Cleanup Task to get a quick and dirty backup schedule going. Are you doing something besides this?

Comment: Just thought of something. In your Back Up Database Task, make sure you have Create a backup file for every database selected. This is the options that creates individual files if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A maintenance cleanup task will do exactly what you are looking for, use the default backup task, with a BAK each day with a time stamp, and add a cleanup task to remove files more than 5 days old.

Comment: i dont see a "with a time stamp" option

Answer (score 1):

Read this free ebook if you want to know a little bit more about maintenance plans, it wont take much time and its worth it. [Brad's Sure Guide to SQL Server Maintenance Plans](http://www.red-gate.com/about/book_store/sql_server_maintenance_plans.htm)